# SQL: Removing rows based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to remove the values of columns which is easily doable with for loops and if conditions. However, I don't know how to do in SQL. The table that I have looks like the following

```
dt   _______ level ________ cohort_size ________ daily_users
2020 _______ D5    ________ 345.        ________ 12
2020 _______ D3    ________ 32          ________ 32
2019 _______ D0    ________ 78.         ________ 78 
2019 _______ D4.   ________ 67          ________ 56
2018 _______ D0    ________ 56          ________ 9
```

What I am trying to do is to remove the rows where the level is D0 and the cohort_size = daily active users. So basically I should only remove row 3. Everything else remains the same. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `where` clause.  One method follows your logic directly:

```
select t.*
from t
where not (level = 'D0' and cohort_size = daily_users);
```

Note:  For this to work, it assumes that the three columns are not `NULL`.  It can easily be tweaked to handle that.

If you actually want to remove the row from the table, use `delete`:

```
delete t from t
    where level = 'D0' and cohort_size = daily_users;
```